Build failed: Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' in Flutter project
I'm trying to build a Flutter application for Android using the flutter build apk command, but the build fails with the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 953ms
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1.604ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1


I try with this configurations

Configuration Files
settings.gradle
include ':app'
include ':firebase_core'
project(':firebase_core').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.9.0/android')

Project-level build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        minSdkVersion = 21
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

App-level build.gradle
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gustaga.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':firebase_core')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}

firebase_core build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
}

i've ensured that all the configurations are correct, but the issue persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

you don't need these two line of code in settings.gradle file
include ':firebase_core'
project(':firebase_core').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.9.0/android')

